# Outlook Calendar API not giving right start and end times

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to fetch events from user's outlook calendar using this endpoint:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/${calendar.id}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/$%7Bcalendar.id%7D/events)

The API gives the start and end times in UTC and I am converting them to the user's timezone, in this case, Asia/Kolkata (UTC+5:30).

[image: Start and End time of event]

In my app, the start time comes up to 12:00 (Adding 5:30 to 06:30), but in the outlook calendar, the same event has the start time as 13:00.

[image: Outlook calendar Image]

See the one on friday.

All the other events are working as expected, but this one event has this issue. Also can it be related to Daylight savings Time? But DST is not observed in India.

Comment: And what's the correct start time? 12:00 or 13:00? Could you check what's the time zone for your calendar? GET /me/mailboxSettings/timeZone

Comment: As per the User, correct time should be 13:00 as the event is appearing on 13:00 on their outlook calendar. But the API returns start time as 06:30 in UTC.

Comment: Let me check the the endpoint you mentioned.

Comment: I didn't have the access for the end endpoint GET /me/mailboxSettings/timeZone but I got the original originalStartTimeZone from endpoint GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{{outlookEventId}} and it is W. Europe Standard Time

Comment: It can explain the difference. There was a time change in West Europe at the end of October. One hour backward. Looks like some miscalculation by the Graph API.